# Косвенное присвоение значений переменным

Tags: linux, bash

Скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
test1=""
test2=""
t_array=( "test1" "test2" )

index=$((${#t_array[@]}-1))
while [ $index -gt -1 ]
do
  ${t_array[index]}="1"
  index=$(($index-1))
done

echo $test1 $test2
```

возвращает ошибку.

Как реализовать присвоение значений заранее заданным переменным?

Comment: Простите, исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если запустить ваш скрипт, получаем ошибки в девятой строке (содержащей `${t_array[index]}="1"`):

> /tmp/s: line 9: test2=1: command not found
>   /tmp/s: line 9: test1=1: command not found

т.е. сформированная строка интерпретируется как **буквальное** выполнение строки `test2=1` как команды. такой команды, конечно, нет, о чём интерпретатор и сообщает.

судя по содержимому скрипта, в этом месте необходимо **интерпретировать** эту строку, чтобы она воспринималась интерпретатором как присвоение значения переменной. это можно сделать, например, добавив команду `eval` перед выражением, формирующим строку:

```
eval ${t_array[index]}="1"
```

тогда скрипт вернёт строку

```
1 1
```

что, вероятно, и ожидается.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! Не нашел подобного примера, а вот реализация именно такая нужна, все остальное ужасно неудобно.

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).